# Do I need SSL certificate on all ShP servers or just on frontend ones?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, iis, ssl

We have 2 FE servers and 1 BE server on which we installed ShP2013.
We use SP only in intranet environment.
I used to add/import on all servers SSL certificates for all https WAs and soon I will have to change SSL certificate for one WA.

My question is, do I need SSL imported on back end server too, do I need to add in bindings in all servers where we have Sharepoint installed SSL certificate or just on FE servers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSL certificates required on SharePoint web front end servers only. Web front are the server which respond the user's request. Even though you are can see IIS sites on other backend server but those never respond to the end user directly.

Comment: I see. Thanks. That's why I asked do I have to import SSL cert to BE too.

Answer (score 1):

if you are speaking about the SSL Cert i would prefer to keep all servers in sync with the same SSL cert. so that from next time if cert needs to be changed in that way you need to use the same cert in all the servers

Coming to Binding part

First take the screenshots before changing anything
then try to see on what binding has the SSL cert set for
change that binding

If you dont find to see any cert binding in FE or BE servers you must check if that cert is running on the VIP servers

Answer (score 1):

yes, you need to install the certificate on all SharePoint servers has IIS